# How to split a string into specfic groups?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I have a list of names I'm getting from a SQL query. They are in the form:

```
[('Lastname Firtsname Middlename',), ('Lastname Firstname',)].
```

I'm having a difficult time parsing the names. I want them to be in the form:

```
Firstname Middlename Lastname , Firstname Lastname
```

Could someone advise me on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Split the tuples and arrange by index? Try it?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? It is not even clear what output you want. A single string? Another tuple with the strings rearranged?

Comment: Are this two different forms? Or the same name formatted in two forms?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Not sure how this is hard to understand.  She gave the input and the output and is unsure how to get there.  I guess the output could be interpreted as a tuple, a list, a string...but the form of the output isn't really the issue for her, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Assume output is of the form

```
output = [('Lastname Firstname Middlename'), ('Lastname Firstname')]
```

Then

```
last_first_middle = output[0].split()
last_first = output[1].split()

parsed_output = [('{} {} {}').format(last_first_middle[1], last_first_middle[2], last_first_middle[0]), ('{} {}').format(last_first[1], last_first[0])]
```

Which gives the output

```
['Firstname Middlename Lastname', 'Firstname Lastname']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the `list` and take first `index` of the `tuples` and `split` it then append it to another `list`. After that you can `loop` through the new lists and print the values as desired. For example:

```
data = [('Lastname Firtsname Middlename',), ('Lastname Firstname',)]
first = [data[0][0].split()]
second = [data[1][0].split()]
for x, y in zip(first, second):
    print x[1], x[2], x[0] + ' , ' + y[1], y[0]
```

output:

```
Firtsname Middlename Lastname , Firstname Lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

So we actually have 5 words inside 2 strings inside a structure of tuples and lists.

To access each of the words, we need to understand the structures and how to access them.

List access is easy: `item[0]` and `item[1]`

Now, `item[0]` will contain a tuple.  To access this tuple we need another index.  So `item[0][0]` will contain our 3 word string and `item[1][0]` will contain our 2 word string.

Now we just need to split the strings.  `item[0][0].split()` will give us a list containing 3 entries: `['Lastname', 'Firtsname', 'Middlename']`.  `item[1][0].split()` will give us a list containing 2 entries: `['Lastname', 'Firstname']`

Finally, we need to create our output string.  All we need to do is access our 2 strings in the order we want our access string to be in.

I'll throw the first pass code below and you can make it more efficient to your heart's content

```
def FirstPass(input):
    name_3part = input[0][0].split()
    name_2part = input[1][0].split()
    output_part1 = ' '.join(name_3part[1], name_3part[2], name_3part[0])
    output_part2 = ' '.join(name_2part[1], name_2part[0])
    output = ', '.join(output_part1, output_part2)
    return output
```

You can create loop constructions and conditional outputs as needed, but for your input to your requested output, this simple and easy to follow brute force code might be better than the more imaginative examples.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list, split each tuple item `0` (i.e., the only item in each tuple) and index it. This function returns a `list` of names in first-middle-last. Modify if needed.

```
names = [('Lastname Firtsname Middlename',), ('Lastname Firstname',)]

def formatnames(names):
    new_names = []
    for name in names:
        n = name[0].split()
        new_names.append('{} {}'.format(' '.join(n[1:]),n[0]))
    return new_names

formatnames(names)
```

Returns:

```
['Firtsname Middlename Lastname', 'Firstname Lastname']
```

To return a *single* string of all names, change the `return` statement:

```
return ' , '.join(new_names)
```

Which returns:

```
'Firtsname Middlename Lastname , Firstname Lastname'
```

**OR** to preserve the output as a `list` of `tuple`, change the `new_names.append` statement:

```
new_names.append(('{} {}'.format(' '.join(n[1:]),n[0]),))
```

Which returns:

```
[('Firtsname Middlename Lastname',), ('Firstname Lastname',)]
```